# Postgres Query to select value based on two different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am making a dating app, I am storing user swipes in a swipe table.

Each swipe is a row. I would like a query that would return all matches for a specific user.

Ex: User 1 swiped on user 2, the owner column would contain id 1 and target id 2. If user 2 swipes on user 1 there would be another row where user 2 is the owner and 1 is the target.

Since both users swiped on each other they matched. I would need a query to find all matches for a particular user ID

How can I go about doing this?

```
+-------+--------+
| owner | target |
+-------+--------+
| A     | B      |
+-------+--------+
| B     | A      |
+-------+--------+
| C     | X      |
+-------+--------+
| D     | E      |
+-------+--------+
| E     | Y      |
+-------+--------+
```

If the above is your table structure, in the above case A and B  is a match.

Comment: Doing what?  You haven't explained what you want to accomplish.

Comment: So I am making a dating app, I am storing user swipes in a swipe table, so each swipe is a row. I would like a query that would return all matches for a specific user. 

Ex: User  1 swiped on user 2, the owner column would contain id 1 and target id 2. If user 2 swipes on user 1 there would be another row where user 2 is the owner and 1 is the target. Since both users swiped on each other they matched. 

I would need a query to find all matches for a particular user ID.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. You need to show us the actual table structure, some sample records, etc., otherwise we can't ask. Describing is a _lot_ less clear than _showing_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS condition

```
select t1.owner, t1.target
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              the_table t2
              where t1.owner = t2.target
                and t1.target = t2.owner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to self join.

```
select s1.owner  
     , s1.target
   from swipe s1 
   join swipe s2 
     on (    s2.owner = s1.target
         and s1.owner = s2.target
        ) 
  order by s1.owner;
```

This will produce 2 rows for each set. With this particular data (A with B) and (B with A). If you only want one set combination add a where clause to remove 1 of them.

```
select s1.owner  
     , s1.target
   from swipe s1 
   join swipe s2 
     on (    s2.owner = s1.target
         and s1.owner = s2.target
        ) 
  where s1.owner < s2.owner
  order by s1.owner;
```